# How to Displayed cc(subtitle) in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I use XML attribute URL for playing a video. And I used By default media player in Roku. I know Roku is provided By default option to display a subtitle. In the video I played in VLC Media Player there provided to CC. But any separate code required for display a subtitle or CC in Roku?

I tried this way **EDITED POST:**

```
m.liveVideo = m.top.findNode("liveVideo") '<Video id = "liveVideo" />
m.videoData = CreateObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")
m.videoData.SubtitleConfig = {
        trackName: "eia608/708"
}
m.videoData.ClosedCaptions = "true"
m.liveVideo.content = m.videoData
```

But above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `SubtitleTracks` property and the standard for live streams is usually `"eia608/1"` (See [here](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/getting-started/architecture/content-metadata.md)). Also, don't worry about the `ClosedCaptions` property, is true by default.

Here's how you should construct the `subtitleTracks` field:

```
m.liveVideo = m.top.findNode("liveVideo")
m.videoData = CreateObject("roSGNode", "ContentNode")
m.videoData.subtitleTracks = [{language: "EN", description: "EN", trackName: "eia608/1"}]
m.videoData.subtitleConfig = {trackName: "eia608/1"}
m.liveVideo.content = m.videoData
```

Comment: Is it possible to content meta data in XML. Like these e.g. <item subtitleTracks = "language:EN, description:EN, trackName:eia608/1" subtitleConfig = "trackName:eia608/1" title="ABC" LIVE="true" shortdescriptionline1="ABC" url="http://roku.cpl.delvenetworks.com/media/59021fabe3b645968e382ac726cd6c7b/f8de8daf2ba34aeb90edc55b2d380c3f/b228eeaba0f248c48e01e158f99cd96e/rr_123_segment_1_072715.mp4" streamformat="hls" hdposterurl="http://66.210.244.200:2200/nodeapi/Channels/file-1559916027835.jpg" description-color="0xC36419" />

Comment: No, is not possible, the content has to be set in the brs source.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and Is it possible to fix the position of CC in Roku?

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya No problem. Please ask how to modify the captions position on a different question.

Comment: Roku support multiple audio track?

Answer (score 0):

In Roku, you have to set the "**SubtitleConfig**" for video's **content-metadata**. And make sure that "**ClosedCaptions**" is set to true. It's easy to implement. For detail info, please have a look at below link--

https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/getting-started/architecture/content-metadata.md

For explanation consider below example--

1. Suppose your "videoPlayer" (instance of 'Video' Node in xml file ) node instance is "m.videoPlayer"( in brs file) i.e.

   `m.videoPlayer = m.top.findNode("videoPlayer")`
2. Create a content node--

   `m.videoData = CreateObject("RoSGNode", "ContentNode")`
3. Set all the meta-data (for example url, Streamformat etc ) of video for this node along with SubtitleConfig as--

   `m.videoData.SubtitleConfig = {
       trackName: "eia608/708"
   }`
4. Assign this content to video content as--

   `m.videoPlayer.content = m.videoData`

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply It's possible to as a string I write SubtitleConfig tag in my XML. I used m3u8 video format

Comment: Hi @NikunjChaklasiya Don't know how you are specifying in xml file. I set this field in brightscript file. I edited my answer with sample code. Please checkout it.

Comment: <item title="demo" description-color="0xC36419" hdposterurl="file-1563875069958.jpg" streamformat="hls" url="https://l1uqyex-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/765405/livestreamC/demo.m3u8" shortdescriptionline1="demo" LIVE="true" SubtitleConfig="trackName:eia608/708" /> I used directly Put into a XML item tag as content node

Comment: I tried Both the way but doesn't show any output. Closed captioning mode select on "on always".

Comment: It should work. Please review your code once. If still problem persist, please share the code. will check in 1-2 days and let you know if I could be able to resolve it.

Comment: I Edit my post pls check

Comment: here I upload both the file https://github.com/chaklasiyanikunj/KeyboardDialogExample file name is videoplayer

Comment: where you are setting url in file. i.e. m.videoData.url = ?? and where  you set to play the video i.e. m.liveVideo.control = "play" ? Add these to play the video.

Comment: yes, I add this statement and Url retrieve from XML.

Comment: Are you correctly able to fetch the url? are you assigning the url to required node? are you setting the fields properly? Please check your code once. It has implementation flaws. Otherwise it will take time to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and Its add subtitleTracks attribute and I required to debug code.

Comment: Is it possible to change the subtitle Position?